# How can I use NLTK to repharse a sentence or a paragraph

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to use NLTK to rephrase a sentence or a paragraph which is grammatically correct. I am aware of article spinners but they generally just replace words with their synonyms. So, is there a way to easily use NLTK to generate sentences with a different structure than the original but essentially give the same meaning?

For eg, "How to make a passive income from a website"
"How can you make a residual income form your website"
"Here's how you can make a residual income from your website"

Something like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything "easy" beyond using synonyms.
The successful solutions for paraphrasing (like the ones winning SemEval Task 1 on text similarity - http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task1/) are based on deep learning and Word2Vec word/sentence similarity.

You can browse through the proceedings to get the idea (link on the page above).

The winning approach for English (the idea applicable for other languages as well): https://aclweb.org/anthology/S/S16/S16-1091.pdf

Comment: I am sorry for your situation but I wonder how does this relate to the topic of the question or my answer?

Comment: Hi Sophoros, I am so sorry I replied to the wrong answer.

Comment: thanks for those links. I will definitely check them out. I was thinking maybe there is some sort of a library that I could just include and use :) I found some online tools that converted sentences from active voice to passive but it was so so and didn't work well for all kinds of sentences. It seems paraphrasing is a real tricky thing. I found something interesting here http://www.theverge.com/2015/1/29/7939067/ap-journalism-automation-robots-financial-reporting but I think it would require a lot of machine learning stuff to implement this kind of thing.

Comment: Indeed. Apple's solution goes beyond simple paraphrasing.